# My google app script takes longer to run how can I minimize the run time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function test() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = ss1.getActiveSheet();
  var only = ['AutoGR', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'];
  if (only.indexOf(ss.getName()) == -1) return;
  var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  var range;
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    range = ss.getRange('B' + i);
    if (range.getValues() == "Crate") {
      range.offset(0, 4).setValue(3000);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    range = ss.getRange('B' + i);
    if (range.getValues() == "Pallet") {
      range.offset(0, 4).setValue(4200);
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is if values in column B = ‘Crate’ then in the same row under column named Qty put value automatically as 3000, if values in column B = ‘Pallet’ then Qty column automatically gets updated as 4200 but when B=‘close operation’ I have to add qty manually.

Comment: App script takes 40-60 sec to run one trigger. How can I make it 1-2 sec ?

Comment: Get all of the data at one time with getValues() instead of using getValue() in a loop.  You will see a 10X improvement in speed

Comment: Takes 25 sec now

Comment: @cooper any updated version in this to make it real faster

Comment: Please share your code.  And provide an explanation of what you are doing

Comment: function test() {
  
   var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var ss = ss1.getActiveSheet();
    var only  = ['AutoGR']
    if (only.indexOf(ss.getName()) == -1)
    return;
   var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
   var range;
   
    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      range = ss.getRange('B' + i );
      if (range.getValues() == "Crate") {
        range.offset(0, 4).setValue(3000); 
          }
    }
      if (range.getValues() == "Pallet") {
        range.offset(0, 4).setValue(4200); 
        
        }
    }

Comment: Please post it into your question as  updated version of code

Comment: No.  That's a ridiculous way to use getValues().  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I just added explanations that based on values in column B I automatically want to update column named Qty.

Comment: I used arrayformula but it doesn’t allow me to change Qty manually. So I tried app script and it worked but takes too much time

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting Column F in multiple sheets using getValues() and setValues()

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const incl = ['AutoGR', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'];
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~incl.indexOf(sh.getName()));
  shts.forEach(sh => {
    let bs = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
    let fs = sh.getRange(1,6,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
    bs.forEach((r,i) => {
      if(r[0] == "Crate") {
        fs[i][0] = 3000;
      } else if(r[0] == "Pallet") {
        fs[i][0] = 4200;
      } 
    })
    sh.getRange(1,6,fs.length,1).setValues(fs);
  })
}
```

If this causes problems in other cells in F then you may be forced to write to F one cell at a time but you'll still get better performance on the read side.

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: Thank you so much cooler, worked perfectly fine. My savior..